# Swift - The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I am developing a  project to learn how to parse JSON. I am trying to parse **JSON** to a **struct**. I am trying to do it using the code that comes next but I am getting the following error:

> Err The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

What am I doing wrong? Also I tried to use Alamofire but I didn't find way to parse it to struct.

```
func getData(){
    let gitUrl = URL(string: "http://95.46.99.250:9095/api/v1/institution-categories")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: gitUrl!) { (data, response
        , error) in
        let data = data
        print(data)
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let gitData = try decoder.decode([Root].self, from: data!)

        } catch let err {
            print("\nErr", err.localizedDescription)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Struct

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let  data: [InnerItem]
}
struct InnerItem:Codable {
    let  id: Int?
    let  image: String?
    let  name: String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id", image = "image", name = "name"
    }
}
```

JSON

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Пабы и бары",
        "image": "http://95.46.99.250:9095/storage/photos/beer@2x.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Кафе",
        "image": "http://95.46.99.250:9095/storage/photos/coffee@3x.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Ночной клуб",
        "image": "http://95.46.99.250:9095/storage/photos/0201f7523bc2028f174710b51379e432.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Ресторан",
        "image": "http://95.46.99.250:9095/storage/photos/restaurants@3x.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Караоке-клуб",
        "image": "http://95.46.99.250:9095/storage/photos/microphone.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Суши-бар",
        "image": "http://95.46.99.250:9095/storage/photos/sushi.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Пиццерии",
        "image": "http://95.46.99.250:9095/storage/photos/pizza.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Кальянная",
        "image": "http://95.46.99.250:9095/storage/photos/c111d1e5ad6b90b61ac36836d220ebba.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Общая",
        "image": "http://95.46.99.250:9095/storage/photos/Group 315@3x.png"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: `[Root].self` to `Root.self`? Your JSON is not an Array at top level. Also, don't use localizedDescription, print the full error, and it should be more explicit then.

Comment: ... and (although not related to the issue) remove the redundant CodingKeys in `InnerItem` and all question marks as the JSON dictionaries clearly contain always all keys. `image` can even be decoded as `URL`

Comment: Don't print the localizedDescription because it has no context. Print the error to see exactly where the serialization failed.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

## Troubleshoot `coding`/`decoding` errors

When working with `codable`s, instead of printing `.localizedDescription`, try to print out the `error` itself! so the compiler describes where the issue exactly is!

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let decoded = try decoder.decode([Root].self, from: data!)
} catch {
    // print(error.localizedDescription) // <- ⚠️ Don't use this!

    print(String(describing: error)) // <- ✅ Use this for debuging!
}
```

---

#### ✅ In your case

it will point out that:

- Decoder tried to decode the root object to an `Array` but found a `Dictionary` instead.

So you follow the issue and see that you should replace:

```
decoder.decode([Root].self, from: data!)
```

with:

```
decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data!)
```

Comment: print(String(describing: error)) // <- ✅ Use this for debuging!                                    
Thanks man, This line is really helpful .

Comment: i am using same but found same issue

Comment: Thanks man! This line is great! (I was trying to put a float "disguised" as an int in an int) :/

Comment: +1000 for The print statement

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
let gitData = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data!)
```

Traverse through your data

```
for singleData in gitData.data where (singleData.name ?? "") == "Cafe" {
    print(singleData.image)
}
```

Comment: So i get data inside my stuct... Now, how i can get data from InnerItem. For example if InnerItem.name == cafe GET InnerItem.image for this name

Comment: This way i will get all images... how i can relate them with name? if InnerItem.name == cafe GET InnerItem.image

Comment: If you can traverse, you can add necessary condition as you go. I have added one which will print the URL of the image of which name is "Cafe"

Answer (score -3):

For me, the issue with "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." was something to do with the specific XLSX file I was trying to use.  I created a new XLSX file in Excel, and added it to my project and that worked!   Then I just pasted the data I needed from the file that was giving me the error into the newly created XLSX file and it parsed!

```
    static func load() {
    
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "xlsx", inDirectory: nil) else {
        fatalError("XLSX file not exist")
    }
    
    let file = XLSXFile(filepath: filePath)
    
    do {
                   
        let parseBooks = try? file?.parseWorkbooks()
        
        for eachBook in parseBooks! {
            
            for (name, path) in try file!.parseWorksheetPathsAndNames(workbook: eachBook) {
    
                let worksheet = try file!.parseWorksheet(at: path)
                let sharedStrings = try file!.parseSharedStrings()
                print(sharedStrings)
    
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question except the same meaningless generic error message. Even in your case replace `error.localizedDescription` with `error` to get the underlying **real** error.