# Swift 4 Get data from structure

Tags: swift, structure, extract

I have structure (Code below), i put there JSON values. How i can get **image:URL** for **name: cafe** from my struct?

for example:

- **name: "cafe"  image: "url_link"**
- **name: "bar"  image: "url_link"**
- **name: "sushi"  image: "url_link"**

My Struct

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let  data: [InnerItem]
}
struct InnerItem:Codable {
    let  id: Int?
    let  image: String?
    let  name: String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id", image = "image", name = "name"
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - you don't need to define `CodingKeys` if the keys all match your property names.

Comment: … and – as already mentioned in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386257/swift-4-the-data-couldn-t-be-read-because-it-isn-t-in-the-correct-format) – declare the struct members as non-optional (no question marks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
do {
      let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: response.data!)
      let innerCafe = decoder.data.first(where: { $0.name == "cafe" })   
  }
  catch {
      print(error)
  }
```