# How to extract and make specific arrays from JSON in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4

I am very new in swift and trying to extract information from a Json response and save them in some separate arrays.

Here is my Json:

```
{
    "result": {
        "date": [
            {
                "TestDate": 970606
            },
            {
                "TestDate": 980703
            }
        ],
        "headId": [
            {
                "AreaCode": 200,
                "AreaName": "center"
            },
            {
                "AreaCode": 300,
                "AreaName": "Middle"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to have an array for `AreaName` and another array for `TestDate`.

Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Let's say you already have all the networking setup needed to get json. Now in order to parse the JSON in to your swift structure you can make use of Codable protocol. This tutorial might help: https://blog.pusher.com/swift-4-decoding-json-codable/

Comment: This should also be able to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386257/swift-4-the-data-couldn-t-be-read-because-it-isn-t-in-the-correct-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You decode the JSON with `Decodable` and then pick off the pieces you want from it:

```
import Foundation

struct Response: Decodable {
    struct Result: Codable {
        let headID: [HeadID]
        let date: [DateElement]

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case headID = "headId"
            case date
        }
    }

    struct DateElement: Codable {
        let testDate: Int

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case testDate = "TestDate"
        }
    }

    struct HeadID: Codable {
        let areaCode: Int
        let areaName: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case areaCode = "AreaCode"
            case areaName = "AreaName"
        }
    }

    let result: Result
}

let data = """
{
  "result": {
    "headId": [
      {
        "AreaCode": 200,
        "AreaName": "center"
      },
      {
        "AreaCode": 300,
        "AreaName": "Middle"
      }
    ],
    "date": [
      {
        "TestDate": 970606
      },
      {
        "TestDate": 980703
      }
    ]
  }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
let areaNames = response.result.headID.map { $0.areaName }
let testDates = response.result.date.map { $0.testDate }

print(areaNames)
print(testDates)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering. What can i do if i want to GET my json data from a URL?

Comment: Can you make a new question with the details of what you are trying to get? I don't have enough information here to help you with that

Answer (score 0):

What I use that saves me a lot of time is a website that will translate the JSON structure to Swift for me.   https://app.quicktype.io/

It's super duper helpful, and usually works perfectly just by copying and pasting the structures and classes into my Swift file.